# Grails import groovy http builder

Tags: java, grails, groovy, import

i´m using grails and

i want to use the http builder http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/doc/

when i follow the examples like :

```
import groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder
```

or sth. i found here on SO

```
 @Grab(group='org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder', module='http-builder', version='0.5.0-RC2' )
```

it throws an error :

```
unable to resolve class groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder
```

what am i doing wrong ? what can i do to make it work ? 

 
 
Please note that i want to use the groovy http builder and not some magic grails-rest plugin

thanks for any Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you could do

In your BuildConfig.groovy add below lines under dependencies.

```
runtime 'org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.5.0-RC2'
```

Do a clean and compile after that and then it should pick up your classes.

Comment: do i have to add sth. to the application.properties file ? since that change the app doesnt compile on live server throwing : java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter.<init>(

Comment: @johnSmith - Hard to tell what is going wrong. Can you try generating a war and then testing the war on your local machine.

Answer (score 2):

this config is in my project, using grails 2.3.7

```
    dependencies {
        // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile',
        // 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes eg.
        compile('org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.5.2') {
//            excludes "xml-apis", "groovy"
        }
    }
```